# Does createMuiTheme provide default values for missing properties?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a theme using `createMuiTheme()`:

```
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: 'dark',
      primary: {
        main: '#c5cae9',
        light: '#f8fdff',
        dark: '#9499b7',
        contrastText: '#212121',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#5c6bc0',
        light: '#8e99f3',
        dark: '#26418f',
        contrastText: '#ffffff',
      },
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: [
        'Roboto',
        'Arial',
        '"Helvetica"',
        'sans-serif',
      ].join(','),
    },
  }),
);

export default theme;
```

When looking at the [default theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/), I'm missing a lot of properties like `breakpoints`, `direction`, `shadows`, `spacing`, and etc.

Even when those properties are omitted, does `createMuiTheme()` provide default values that populate those fields? Or do I have to provide those values myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `createMuiTheme` `options` signature

```
(Object): Takes an incomplete theme object and adds the missing parts.
```

So yes, your custom theme will be merged with `MUI`'s default theme. See the [docs here](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#createmuitheme-options-theme)

```
const options = {palette:{/*such empty*/}}

export const theme = createMuiTheme(options)
```